# Any Online R console?

Tags: r, statistics

I am looking for an online console for the language R. Like I write the code and the server should execute and provide me with the output.

Similar to the website Datacamp.

Comment: Here you have good options for R Programming: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_r_online.php

Comment: I am also having this issue. Most of the links above require signing up and that is not something I want to do haha. I have been using https://rdrr.io/snippets/ which works generally though I was trying to see if there is something that will let me do a qplot for free online (again without a signup). Just an fyi.

Answer (score 28):

- [R On Cloud](http://roncloud.com) provides a browser-embedded R-console.

[image: screenshot-roncloud]

- [Jupyter.org](https://jupyter.org/) evolved from the [IPython Project](http://ipython.org/) (the language-agnostic parts of IPython); supports Python 3, Julia, R, Haskell, Ruby, etc.

[image: jupyter screenshot]

Comment: R on Cloud is gone.

Answer (score 9):

While I have only had a brief look at it, I think [CoCalc](https://cocalc.com/) (formerly [SageMathCloud](https://cloud.sagemath.com/)) looks quite promising. I have recommended it to at least one person previously, and they seemed to be quite happy with it. Beyond R support, you also get access to Python, SAGE (as the name indicates), and a few other things.

EDIT: Make sure to check the [documentation](https://github.com/sagemath/cloud/wiki/FAQ#useR) on how to get an R (as opposed to a Python) session in a worksheet.

Comment: In a Sage Worksheet (".sagews"), just enter `%default_mode r` and evaluate the cell. Then you talk to R directly.

Comment: In SageMathCloud at http://cloud.sagemath.com, you can also start a Jupyter Notebook and select "change kernel > R".

Answer (score 5):

Yes. I believe [this](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_r_online.php) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily have an RStudio server installed in Digital Ocean using [this](https://github.com/sckott/analogsea) package.

Comment: This pakage is on CRAN now https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/analogsea/

Answer (score 3):

[RStudio Server](http://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/#Server) is definately one of the options, meant exactly for this. I've thought about using it with a cloud virtual machine, but haven't had the need yet. But when I (probably) need to prepare an intro data analysis class for the fall semester, then Rstudio Server is the first option I'll be trying out.

Answer (score 2):

I am using this one, so far so good.
Online terminals: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/codingground.htm

Also, [R-Fiddle](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/) is an option.

Answer (score 2):

[RStudio Cloud](https://rstudio.cloud/) is the best I've used.

It offers the total R-Studio experience online. Most other sandboxes from this list either didn't work, were permanently closed, or required monthly fees.

RStudio Cloud is free, but does require a login, but you can sign in with your Google account, and it saves your progress (History and such) so you can access it from any computer.

Here's a screenshot from my first project, you can see it's the same as the R-Studio you can download. I haven't tried to hit it with anything heavy yet, but I assume it's probably not as nimble as a local instance - and most likely depends on how many people are using it at the same time.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try out AirXcell : [AirXcell calculation software](http://airxcell.com).
See documentation [Use AirXCell as an r Console](http://www.airxcell.com/doc/howTo/useConsole.html)

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged. Please in-line why you recommend this tool.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.codeschool.com/ is very similar to https://www.datacamp.com/
when I tried it I fell in love with R and then found datacamp.
www.codecademy.com  is also console-based but R is not yet available.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Notebooks should allow you to use multiple languages (R included). Unfortunately they are free only up to some (limited) amount of RAM. Still better than nothing.